# How to call this component method from other component's event listener ($on)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've read about Non-Parent-Child Communication here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication. An idea with listening to bus events is clear.

But it's still unclear how to call other components's methods from bus listener.
For example how can I call *lst.additem2()* from *eventHub.$on('lst:additem', function()* ?
It seems that **this** in there has eventHub context (basing at *console.log( this.$data)* result ).

There is my example

```
Vue.component('lst', {
template: `
   <ul>
     <li v-for="(item, index) in items" :good='item' :key="item.id">
       <item :it='item' :index="index" ></item>
     </li>
   </ul>`,
created: function () {
  this.eventHub.$on('lst:additem', function(d) { 
    console.log( d );
    console.log( this.$data.tip );
    // this.additem2(d); this won't work :(
  });
},
methods: {
  additem2 : function(newitem) {
    console.log( '...here '+newitem.weight );
    this.items.push( newitem );
    console.log( 'item added' );
  }
}
```

more on JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0mx8mtcj/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are listening:

```
  this.eventHub.$on('lst:additem', function(d) { 
    // `this` here refers to the bus instance
  });
```

So just save a reference of the component:

```
var self = this;
this.eventHub.$on('lst:additem', function(d) { 
  self.additem2(d);
});
```

Comment: @DimaFomin Easy on yourself, glad to help.